# How to start a nodeagent

Tags: websphere

Hi after changing ownership I getting problem to start nodeagent and servers but dmgr started with the user node agent and servers starting with root but not starting with user

00000001 ORBRas        E com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTransport createServerSocket P=146590:O=0:CT ORBX0390E: Cannot create listener thread. Exception=[ java.net.BindException: The socket name is already in use. - received while attempting to open server socket on port 9101

Comment: The error is about socket exception, is there other server instances running on the same machine?

Comment: What to do next

Comment: Ypu still have java process that is using 9101 port. If you dont know which process is holding the port, stop/kill all java processes and restart them.

Answer (score 0):

Please use ps -ef |grep java| grep 9101, maybe used for another process

Thanks and regards

tandn

So after use kill -9 processid java used and start nodeagent with command:

```
/app/TPSrv10/bin/startNode.sh
```